# Re-line long strings and replace with shorter strings

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a page where a user can input a random comment and it should display the comment below. (as seen below)
The problem I have is that I want to make all the boxes fit within the page. For example, the longer strings should move to a new line and be replaced with shorter strings, etc.

[image]

At the moment I have each output as a `<span>` whilst I test. 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you post some HTML and CSS?

Comment: where is the array?

Comment: What does the "longest array" have to do with this?

Comment: Apologies, the heading was for an older post. Did not see the incorrect heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`white-space: nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Demo:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Content goes here.
</div>
<div>
  Content goes here.
</div>
<div>
  Content goes here. Content goes here. Content goes here.
</div>
<div>
  Content goes here.
</div>
```

As far as re-ordering the elements to fill the gaps, you might need JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks so much! Will look into the re-odering part a bit more

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with CSS, simpy by using `display` condition.

```
.classname {display:inline-block;}
```

You can also use `block` if you want every element to take a whole line instead.

```
.classname {display:block;}
```

Comment: OP doesn't want the string of text to reflow to a newline. They want all or nothing. If one word wraps, wrap the whole string. This answer does not do this.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should make each div holding the comment to **display : block** and then set it's **maxi-width: 100%**. I think it should work fine. **Note: this would have been a comment, but i can't make** This would make enough space for the text and if text exceed the div, a new line would appear.

Comment: Are you sure this works? Have you tested it? I don't think it will do what OP needs.

Comment: @hungerstar, u aren't the OP and down voting isn't the best thing. My answer is a solution to what i think the OP is asking. Have you checked the image?

Comment: Yes, I've seen the image. OP needs longer text to not wrap and moved to the next line along with filling the gap left by longer text with shorter text. [This is what your solution does](https://jsfiddle.net/z6hdqrq1/1/) and meets [criteria for down vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). PS - I didn't down vote you.